# Partial italics, axis.text.x

Tags: r, ggplot2

Aloha,

For the following bar graph:

```
x <- ggplot(foo, aes(x=variety, y=percent)) + geom_bar()
```

The following italicizes all of my x-axis text:

```
x + opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(face='italic'))
```

However, I would like to italicize only the species names, not the control.

```
levels(foo$variety)
"control"    "species1" "species2"     "species3"
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this example:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(CO2, aes(y=uptake,x=Type, group=Type))+
  geom_point()+
  scale_x_discrete("Location", labels=expression(Quebec, italic(Mississippi)))
```

[image]

Comment: I keep on rendering the following error:Labels can only be specified in conjunction with breaks.
When italicizing more then one level would I group them all w/in italics()? I appreciate your help!

Comment: @Droseraaliciae Try specifying a breaks argument. In my example, `breaks=c("Quebec", "Mississippi")`.